# Vapor Session Middleware Alternatives?

Tags: vapor

Are their any alternatives to Vapor's session middleware package?

Our client platform(s) do not support cookies. Vapor uses cookies for it's session management.

Redis has a session store (https://redislabs.com/blog/cache-vs-session-store/ ) provider, but it doesn't appear that Vapor has support for this yet (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What are you requiring Sessions for? Vapor requires the use of the Cookie so that the user can be identified (each session is specific to a user). If you are using something like a token you can probably write your own `TokenSessionsMiddleware` and do pretty much everything the same, but switch out pulling the identifier from the cookie to pulling it out from the token

Comment: My apologies for the delay. We require sessions for anything user-related that needs to persist throughout different views. I'll check into `TokenSessionsMiddleware` . Thank you.